# How do I calculate voltage in a loop antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage, antennas

How do I calculate the effective source voltage applied to the loop by assuming that the loop is perpendicular to the wave magnetic field and that the transmitter transmits the wave evenly in each direction. Loop antennas radius is a 10 cm and transmitter transmit 95 MHz frequency and the power of transmitter is 60kW and the distance between antenna and transmitter is 2000m?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the amplitude required for transmitting a certain amount of power in an antenna, you simply need to know its [radiation resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance), ohmic resistance and reactance. The radiation resistance is basically an effective resistance modelling its power consumption due to the radiation, while the reactance simply models capacitive/inductive effects.  
For a loop antenna, which I'm assuming to be the more conventional "small loop antenna" (where the radius is much smaller than the operating wavelength), the radiation resistance and reactance are approximately given by:
$$R_r \simeq (\frac{177NS}{\lambda^2})^2$$
$$X \simeq \omega \mu_0 a \Big(\ln(\frac{8a}{p})-1.75\Big)$$
where $N$ is the number of turns in the loop, $S$ is the area of each loop, $a$ is the radius of the loop, $p$ is the radius of the wire used in the loop (see [here](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/smallLoop.php)). The units are ohms. The total input impedance of the antenna will be $Z_A=(R_L+R_r)+jX$, with $R_L$ being the resistance due to ohmic losses in your antenna.
With that out of the way, you also need to know what the output impedance of your feeding circuit $Z_G$ is. Assuming that it's perfectly matched, you have $Z_G = Z^*_A$, and your equivalent circuit is simply this (excuse the bad drawing!):
[image]
Knowing the power being radiated $P_{r}$ (for your case $60$ KW)  you can now relate the excitation voltage ($|V_G|$) to it (exercise in Kirchhoff's laws!):
$$|V_G|= (R_r+R_L)\sqrt{\frac{8P_r}{R_r}}$$
So in conclusion, knowing the specifications of your antenna, including any ohmic losses ($R_L$), calculate $R_r$ from the first equation and plug it into the above relation to get the required peak amplitude of your excitation voltage. 
Note that this only works for a matched feeding network. If your excitation circuit is not matched, you'll need to take the reactance into account. You can easily extend the above calculations to this more general case if needed.
For a thorough analysis of loop antennas, see these nice [lecture notes](http://www2.elo.utfsm.cl/~icd342/biblio/antenas/Lectura%2011.pdf).